# Nested if - else in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I am preparing for the OCA 8 examination ...

There was a question in the enthuware test, what is the proper structure of the following code(like which if belongs to which else - without curly brackets)?

```
...

if
    statement 1;
if
    statement 2;
else
    statement 3;
else
    statement 4;

...
```

The answer provided in enthuware was like this ...

```
if //statement 1
|  if //statement 2
|  |
|  else //statement 3
else //statement 4
```

but when I performed the code in the eclipse (without curly brackets), I got a compile time error in the last else...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Syntax error on token "else", delete this token
```

So, is this right/valid/possible?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: This is not valid code. You have 1 if, plus another if with two elses

Comment: @Bohemian I think the second `if` and its `else` are nested in the first `if`. It's hard to follow so I'm probably wrong. Either way, asking a question like this on a test is pointless. It may be valid, but for the love of Pete just use braces.

Comment: The compiler is right, of course.  It's not valid Java code to have two `else` statements like that, no matter how many `if` statements preceded it. It won't automagically see that the last `else` is intended to work with the first `if` without using curlies.  The answer provided in enthuware is wrong, or not about Java.  The answer would match the code if you'd remove the `statement1;` line.

Comment: @DrewKennedy It's not nested because there is `statement 1`. If there was no `statement 1`, then it would be nested because the 2nd `if` would *be* `statement 1`

Comment: @Bohemian Gotcha. Thank you for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not put curly braces, only the first statement after `if()` is considered. In your case, the two `if` statements are nested but the first `else` statement is for the parent `if`, the second `else` hence is without an `if`.

Answer (score -1):

Every if without brackets conditions just one statement after it, so:

```
if(value)
Sys.out.print("Cow");
Sys.out.print("Rabbit");
```

Here, `"Cow"` will be printed if `value` is true. However, `"Rabbit"` will be printed every time. To ensure that two/more instruction execute depending on if statement you have to use block like:

```
if(value){
 Sys.out.print("Cow");
 Sys.out.print("Rabbit");
}
```

So when there is no brackets it wouldn't compile as:

```
if
    statement 2;
else
    statement 3;
```

This is treated as one, and only one else is considered to that if statement. First one "if" is just a standalone if statement, thus second else statement is wrong as it has not if statement before it.

Answer (score -1):

Without curly brackets:

```
if (true)
         System.out.println("First if");
    else
        if (true)
            System.out.println("second if, first else");
        else
            System.out.println("second if, second else");

    System.out.println("outside statement");
```

Though I'd highly recommend adding them:

```
 if (true) {
        System.out.println("First if");
    } else if (true) {
        System.out.println("second if, first else");
    } else {
        System.out.println("second if, second else");
    }

    System.out.println("outside statement");
```